# How many 'importranges' are being used in a selected Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

How to find out how many `importranges` are being used in a single Google Sheet?

Answer (score 1):

The following script is heavily adapted from an Audit Spreadsheet built by Ben Collins.

The logic followed is:

- get the spreadsheet by url [`openByUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl); though the script could just as easily have been bound to the 'IMPORTRANGE' spreadsheet
- get all the sheets [`getSheets()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)and loop through each them

  - get the last row [`getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow), and last column [`getLastColumn()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn),
  - get the data range [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
  - get the formulas [`getFormulas()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas)
  - loop through the cells in the range using Javascript [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method
  - use the Javascript [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method to identify formulas using "IMPORTRANGE", and update a counter
- report on results using a Logger statement

---

```
function wa13548203() {

  /** 
* Adapted by Ted Bell for Webapps StackExchange#135482
* from   
* Google Sheets Performance Auditor tool
* Built by Ben Collins, 2018
* https://www.benlcollins.com
*/

  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TLkuDofF1YDxhYiuwyIB7qCJzlAFqho0c6QPXnDPnM8/edit";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var irTotal = 0;

  sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
    var r = sheet.getLastRow();
    var c = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var data_counter = r * c;
    var irCounter = 0;

    var IR = /.*IMPORTRANGE.*/;

    if (data_counter !== 0) {

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,r,c);
      //Logger.log("sheet = "+sheet.getName()+", range = "+dataRange.getA1Notation());
      var formulaCells = dataRange.getFormulas();

      formulaCells.forEach(function(row) {
        row.forEach(function(cell) {
          if (cell.toUpperCase().match(IR)) { irCounter++ };
        });
      });

      Logger.log("sheet = "+sheet.getName()+", num of 'IMPORTRANGE' formulas = "+irCounter);
      irTotal =irTotal +irCounter  
    }

  }); 
   Logger.log("The total number of IMPORTRANGE formulas is "+irTotal);
}
```